# Use ALT + <F7> to move a window quickly

Tags: shortcut-keys, window-manager

Pressing the `ALT + <F7>` key combination lets you move a window around the screen using the arrow keys, but this is done just 1 row/column at a time.

Is there a way to move the window by 6/7 rows/columns at a time when the arrow key is pressed?

> `lsb_release -a`
>
> No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description:  Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS Release: 18.04 Codename: bionic

> `uname -a`
>
> Linux ricciolino-XPS-15-9570 5.4.0-54-generic #60~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 17:25:16 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Works fine for me in version 18.04.5 - very responsive. Please [edit] your question with at least details of your version of Ubuntu

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work well, I just asked if there is a way to move the window multiple rows (or columns) at a time when pressing a directional arrow on the keyboard once.
I mean maybe there is some method to set up a keyboard shortcut that allows you to do that!

Comment: You said in your OP "but this is done very slowly (just 1 row/column at a time)." but that is not the case on my vanilla 18.04 system.

Comment: I'm using GNOME 3.28.2. Pressing SHIFT transports me the window to the end in the direction of the arrow pressed (among other things, I didn't know this trick, thanks a lot), while pressing CTRL it makes me very very small steps (millimeter).
Anyway I was looking for a way to make steps bigger than the normal step (pressing only the directional arrow) but still not that move me the window to the end of the screen!

Comment: custom shortcut to xdotool key alt+f7 && xdotool <right arrow key> multiple times   .. also you have to unfullscreen if in that state.

Comment: I installd xdotools but I'm unable to reach my goal, please could you provide me full instractions! Thanks